# What do I need to do to make a Reverse colorblind image?

Tags: vision, eyes, light

As a 15 year suffering from moderate Protan colorblindness, I've wanted to find any advantages of colorblindness. I discovered there are Reverse colorblind tests, which only colorblind people are able to see the objects. This has fascinated me, and I want to make one of my own. How can I do this? Since I cannot tell the difference between the colors only visible to colorblind people an their normal vision counterparts, how could I do this without buying a pair of Enchroma colorblind glasses so that I may see it with both visions?